Unexpected Movement in Vue Slider Component on Template Loading
I am using the vue-slider-component in a Vue.js project, and I'm encountering an issue where the slider unexpectedly moves or resets when opening a snapshot template from a download archive. The behavior includes extensions/shrinks in multiple directions, and in some cases, the handles disappear temporarily. I've tried disabling CSS transitions and ensuring proper initialization of the component's state, but the issue persists.
<vue-slider
  v-if="!isDateSelectionOutOfAllowedRange"
  v-model="value"
  :clickable="false"
  :height="sliderHeight"
  :max="maxValue"
  :max-range="maxRangeLength"
  :min="minValue"
  :min-range="minRangeLength"
  :useKeyboard="false"
  silent
  class="slider"
  tooltip="none"
  width="100%"
  @dragging="handleDrag"
  @drag-end="handleDragEnd"
  :railStyle="railStyle"
>
</vue-slider>

Every time on loading it shows an animation like the gif. I want it to stop. It should load the value and stay in the position.


Add :duration="0" as an attribute to the slider

This removes the transition but still jumps. Somehow it keeps old value and then updates! I have no idea why.
